# How does the following Python program work?

Tags: python

I found this code in python simple programs page.

```
parents, babies = (1, 1)
while babies < 100:

    print 'This generation has {0} babies'.format(babies)
    parents, babies = (babies, parents + babies)
```

The output is:

```
This generation has 1 babies
This generation has 2 babies
This generation has 3 babies
This generation has 5 babies
This generation has 8 babies
This generation has 13 babies
This generation has 21 babies
This generation has 34 babies
This generation has 55 babies
This generation has 89 babies
```

Comment: So what part of code is not clear fro you? what you have understand from this code by yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to python. Let's start with the first line.

```
    parents, babies = (1, 1)
```

In this line, the tuple is unpacked to the variables parents and babies. So both will have the value 1. To know what unpacking sequence means you can see [What is sequence unpacking?](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Python/Statement/What_is_sequence_unpacking_in_Python.htm)

I expect u know what a while loop does, so let's look into the third line.

```
    print 'This generation has {0} babies'.format(babies)
```

If u want to know how print.format() work you can see this link [How print.format() work in python](https://mkaz.github.io/2012/10/10/python-string-format/). In short, inside format method you can pass several parameter and use them in print instruction with array like index({0}, {1},{2}, ...). As in this code, format contains a single parameter babies, we can access it with {0} in print statement.

The next line,

```
  parents, babies = (babies, parents + babies)
```

Doing almost same like the first line. It is making a sequence and unpacking with two variables at once. You can do them like that as well:

```
  temp =  parents
  parents = babies
  babies = temp + babies
```

So, now look at the program and guess what it is doing. If you understand everything, you already have the answer. The program is printing the Fibonacci numbers up to 100. Feel free to ask if u have any more question.

Comment: Hi Ahsanul, thank you very very much for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
parents, babies = (1, 1)
```

This is an assignment statement. The value '1' will be assigned to `parents` and `babies` initially.

In the while loop, the value of `babies` will be assigned to `parents` and the sum of `babies` and `parents` will be assigned to `babies`. The loop will end when the value of `babies` goes beyond 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
parents, babies = (1, 1) #This line simply creates the parents and the babies (There are one of each). 

while babies < 100:   #while there are less than 100 babies

    print 'This generation has {0} babies'.format(babies) #his will print the string {0} tells it that the first paramter supplied to the format method should go there.
    parents, babies = (babies, parents + babies) #parent = babies, babies = parents + babies.
```

So first run you have one of each. Second run you have 1 parent, but 2 babies (parents + babies). Then you get 3 babies (2 + 1) and so on.

It's actually just a simple implementation of the fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I am quite clear about this now.